# Determine Range/Conditions for Copy/Paste Procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I need help defining my copy/paste process. I just need an example for the two conditions. The situation is as follows:

- I need to search for for specific keywords in a sheet of wb1 and
  copy/paste it to wb2 under certain conditions.
- I dont know the specific sheet or the position of the keywords, so
  every sheet in the wb should be checked
- In case a keyword is found - condition 1 or condition 2 will be
  applied, depending on the keyword:
- Condition 1: if keyword in wb1 = "mx1" then copy/paste keyword to wb2
  (specific position -> Sheet2, K7) and rename it to "Male". Result
  would be: "Male" in K7 of Sheet2 in wb2.
- Condition 2: if keyword in wb1 = "Data 1" then copy the
  value(integer) of the adjoining cell to the right of it and paste to
  wb2 (specific position -> Sheet3, K3). Result would be: "189" in K7
  of Sheet3 in wb2.
- A keyword can only have one of the conditions assigned.

Actually, my goal is to have a set of keywords, which have condition
   1 or condition 2 assigned, as well as a specific paste-location in
   wb2. So, every sheet should be checked according to the set of
   keywords.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAWLg.jpg

Would appreciate any help!

Code so far - only thing I need is condition 1 and 2....

```
Public Sub TransferFile(TemplateFile As String, SourceFile As String)
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile) 'open source

    Dim rFnd As Range
    Dim r1st As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
    Dim NewWbName As String

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    For Each wsSource In wbSource.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets in source workbook
        Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(TemplateFile) 'open new template

        '/* Definition of the value range */

arr(1) = "mx1"
arr(2) = "Data 1"
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
        Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.Find(what:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
            Set r1st = rFnd
            Do
                If i = 1 Then
                    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = "Male"
                Else
                    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = rFnd.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
                Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.FindNext(rFnd)
            Loop Until r1st.Address = rFnd.Address
        End If
    Next
Next

        NewWbName = Left(wbSource.Name, InStr(wbSource.Name, ".") - 1)
        wbTemplate.SaveAs wbSource.Path & Application.PathSeparator & NewWbName & "_New.xlsx"
        wbTemplate.Close False 'close template
    Next wsSource

    wbSource.Close False 'close source
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search a `Range` for a value, and a range applies to a (part of a) single sheet. So you need to search each worksheet separately. Similarly, you search for a single value, so in this case you need to issue 2 separate searches. I'd do it this way:

```
Dim rFnd As Range
Dim r1st As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr(1 to 2) As Variant
Dim i as Long

arr(1) = "mx1"
arr(2) = "Data 1"
For i = Lbound(arr) to Ubound(arr)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
        Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.Find(what:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
            Set r1st = rFnd
            Do
                If i = 1 then
                    wb2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K7").Value = "Male"
                Else
                    wb2.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K3").Value = rFnd.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
                Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.FindNext(rFnd)
            Loop Until r1st.Address = rFnd.Address
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I define the conditions? I'm pretty new to VBA coding, and not sure how to define Condition 1 and Condition 2.

Comment: @Plutox: Edited the answer.

Comment: sorry, I think I wasnt clear enough :) I dont know how to define the conditions I described above:

**Condition 1**: if keyword in wb1 = "mx1" then copy/paste keyword to wb2 (specific position -> Sheet2, K7) and rename it to "Male". Result would be: "Male" in K7 of Sheet2 in wb2.

**Condition 2**: if keyword in wb1 = "Data 1" then copy the value(integer) of the adjoining cell to the right of it and paste to wb2 (specific position -> Sheet3, K3). Result would be: "189" in K7 of Sheet3 in wb2.

Comment: @AscErno , any ideas? :)

Comment: @Plutox: Edited again

Comment: hello @AcsErno I've updated my code with your code snippets. I doesn't work - and there is no error message at all. The value "Male" and the Integer value are nowhere to be found in the newly created file.... am I missing something? See above my updated code in the original post. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: I have shown you how to go on. I will not prepare the whole macro. This is not a charity code writing service.

Comment: update: its working - just had to rename wb2 to wbTemplate, to allign with the rest of my code. Thanks so much @AcsErno